# Python code location for QGIS functions

Tags: pyqgis, function, qgis-custom-function

Is the Python Code accessible for QGIS function definitions?

My knowledge of Python is limited but I have had success tweaking code in Ruby. So I am willing to give it a try but would like to see the original predefined code rather than starting from scratch. So I can make a few formatting changes and create a custom function.

Here is the code I found posted that I am using for the label:

```
> concat(
   case
     when degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))< 90
       then CONCAT('N',to_dms(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry),
         end_point($geometry))), 'x',0,'aligned'))
     when degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))< 180
       then CONCAT('S', to_dms(180 - degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry),
            end_point($geometry))), 'x',0,'aligned'))
     when degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))< 270
       then CONCAT('S', to_dms(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry),
          end_point($geometry))) -180, 'x',0), 'W')
     else
       CONCAT('N', to_dms(360 - degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry),
          end_point($geometry))), 'x',0), 'W')
   end
 )
```

Comment: For custom algorithms, they are written in Python. For custom expression functions too : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor

Comment: If you want to access to the Python code of each QGIS functions, some are written in Python and can be found on the QGIS projet Github, the other ones are written in C++ so no.

Comment: What I am actually after at the moment is to modify the results of " to_dms " so that it has all 6 formatted digits and a space between d m and s.

Comment: `replace(to_dms(x(centroid(@geometry)), 'x', 0), map('°', ' ', '′', ' ', '″', ' '))` ?

Comment: Hello @J.Monticolo.  That looks really promising but I am not sure what gets substituted and what gets inserted as I am not fluent in Python by any means.  Just enough knowledge and interest to be dangerous. :)    Could you take a look at the label code I added above and see if it will work with that so I don't need to create a whole new function ?

Comment: @Mike, J. Monticolo's suggestion is not Python. It is a field calculator expression that accomplishes what you are aiming for without needing to reinvent the wheel, so to speak. Basically, it converts the X coordinate of your geometry to DMS notation, then it iterates through the `map()`, replacing in the DMS string the 1st element of the map with the 2nd, the 3rd with the 4th and so on. It is a nifty way of doing multiple replacements without having to chain together several `replace` functions.

Comment: Thanks Mike,  I was able to modify what J. provided slightly to get the spacing I wanted like this :  , map('°', '° ', '′', '\' ', '″','" '))      Any way to get all 6 digits of the degrees, minutes, and seconds to display so they all line up in a schedule ?  It seems that it might be the same command used in Ruby. https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html  But not sure how to apply it in Python to this situation.....  .rjust(2, '0')   Perhaps ?     Maybe I do need to write my own Function after all ?